# c# - DirectoryServices - Inaccurate group member count

Tags: c#, .net

I'm sure there is a very simple explanation for this but I can't find it. I'm trying to get a count of members of all groups in our domain and the code below works for the most part but there is one particular group I can't get an accurate count on.   The group has over 1000 members but for some reason the code below keeps returning 0.  Is it due to the number of members? There is nothing special about the group, it's just a normal global security group.

```
DirectoryEntry context = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://MyDomain.test");
DirectorySearcher searchGroups = new DirectorySearcher(context);
searchGroups.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
searchGroups.PageSize = 500;
searchGroups.Filter = "objectClass=group";
searchGroups.PropertiesToLoad.Add("member");

SearchResultCollection searchGroupsResults = searchGroups.FindAll();

foreach (SearchResult group in searchGroupsResults)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Group: " + group.Properties["name"][0].ToString() + " - Member Count: " + group.Properties["member"].Count.ToString());
}
```

This returns:
**Group: MyGroup1 - Member Count: 0**

Group: MyGroup2 - Member Count: 861

Group: MyGroup3 - Member Count: 920

Group: MyGroup4 - Member Count: 9
....

Comment: Set a break point at `SearchResultCollection searchGroupsResults = searchGroups.FindAll();` and inside your `foreach`. Does this return this "MyGroup1", and also check for "property" : `name`

Comment: I did as suggested and confirmed the group is checked withing the foreach loop but the member count returns zero.  Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

It is much more complicated if you query a large group, and Microsoft demonstrated a complex algorithm in C++,

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367017(v=vs.85).aspx

and someone translated to .NET

https://itconnect.uw.edu/wares/msinf/authn/ldap/enumerate-large-groups/

```
...
 using System.DirectoryServices;
 ...

/// <summary>
 /// Determines whether or not the specified user is a member of the group.
 /// </summary>
 /// <param name="UserDN">A System.String containing the user's distinguished name (DN).</param>
 /// <param name="Group">A System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry object of the target group.</param>
 private Boolean IsMemberOfLargeGroup( String UserDN, DirectoryEntry Group )
 {
 Boolean userFound = false;
 Boolean isLastQuery = false;
 Boolean exitLoop = false;
 Int32 rangeStep = 1500;
 Int32 rangeLow = 0;
 Int32 rangeHigh = rangeLow + ( rangeStep - 1 );
 String attributeWithRange;

DirectorySearcher groupSearch = new DirectorySearcher( Group );
 SearchResult searchResults;

groupSearch.Filter = "(objectClass=*)";

do
 {
 if( !isLastQuery )
 attributeWithRange = String.Format( "member;range={0}-{1}", rangeLow, rangeHigh );
 else
 attributeWithRange = String.Format( "member;range={0}-*", rangeLow );

groupSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Clear();
 groupSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add( attributeWithRange );

searchResults = groupSearch.FindOne();
 groupSearch.Dispose();

if( searchResults.Properties.Contains( attributeWithRange ) )
 {
 if( searchResults.Properties[ attributeWithRange ].Contains( userDN ) )
 userFound = true;

if( isLastQuery )
 exitLoop = true;
 }
 else
 {
 isLastQuery = true;
 }

if( !isLastQuery )
 {
 rangeLow = rangeHigh + 1;
 rangeHigh = rangeLow + ( rangeStep - 1 );
 }
 }
 while( ! ( exitLoop | userFound ) );

return userFound;
 }
```

Comment: You are absolutely correct.  Once I got past my initial problem, I ran into this other issue.  My group had over 2500 members but the count only returned 1500.  I ended up using the exact same code you provided.

Answer (score 0):

It might due to your `searchGroups` cannot release all of its unmanaged resources when it is garbage collected, as it stated in msnd:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.findall.aspx

Try wrapping everything in a using, or use `Dispose():`

```
using SearchResultCollection searchGroupsResults = searchGroups.FindAll())
{
    foreach (SearchResult group in searchGroupsResults)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Group: " + group.Properties["name"][0].ToString() + " - Member Count: " + group.Properties["member"].Count.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your help.  I did as you suggested and used the Dispose() method but it didn't help.  I was able to get around the problem by using a DirectoryEntry rather than a SearchResult.  See below.

```
DirectoryEntry context = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://My.Domain.com");
DirectorySearcher searchGroups = new DirectorySearcher(context);
searchGroups.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
searchGroups.PageSize = 500;
searchGroups.Filter = "objectClass=group";
searchGroups.PropertiesToLoad.Add("name");
searchGroups.PropertiesToLoad.Add("member");

SearchResultCollection searchGroupsResults = searchGroups.FindAll();

foreach (SearchResult group in searchGroupsResults)
{
    DirectoryEntry groupDirectoryEntry = group.GetDirectoryEntry();

    Console.WriteLine("Group: " + group.Properties["name"][0].ToString() + " - Member Count: " + groupDirectoryEntry.Properties["member"].Count.ToString());
}
```